# PHP artisan serve command commits changes very slowly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Whenever I try to update my project in Artisan, the commands I run work, but some of them take a very long time to execute.

For instance, here is a section from my `api.php`:

```
Route::apiResource('questions', 'QuestionController');
```

`php artisan serve` works in my terminal, and this route is accessible.

But when I delete this `questions` route, I expect the route `host/questions` to become inaccessible. However for about a minute after running the command, I can still access the route through the normal URL as if it wasn't deleted.

So what exactly is going on here? Is this caused by caching, and if so, how can I prevent this?

I want a leave-reload thing for my Laravel project.

I'm recompiling my files using `ctrl+c`, `php artisan serve` every time, and using Laravel `5.8` with PHP `7.3.7`.

Comment: Try `php artisan cache:clear`?

Comment: @aynber I tried it just now. Not working.

Comment: did you check about opcache?

Comment: @Naco, Ok, It's running. I don't think that I need to disable opcache, but I'll try it

Comment: check php.ini and see if opcache.enable is on "1", if so, change it to 0, and restart php artisan serve

Comment: @Naco, Wow, It works??! Ok, I think that lampp pick-up instead of xampp was not very good idea.

Comment: @Naco, you can post you comment as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably because Opcache keeps a copy of the files for a moment.
Try to disable opcahe and try again.

Check `php.ini` and see if `opcache.enable` is on "1", if so, change it to 0, and restart `php artisan serve`